# How to redirect requests to files with .xml extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my site I want to block access to my xml files

For example, when the following files are requested

```
http://example.com/a_File.xml
```

or

```
http://example.com/some_file.xml
```

I want browser to redirect to a different page  `http://example.com/different_Page.html`.

Here is what I have in `.htaccess` so far:

```
SetEnvIf Request_uri "\.xml$" blocked

RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:blocked} ^blocked 
RewriteRule (.*) 404.php [R=301]
```

It does not stop it, I still can view my xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SetEnvIfNoCase Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html)  to match against Request_URI String in case-insenstive manner  :

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_uri "\.xml$" blocked

RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:blocked} 1 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Strange, it still doesn't work. I still  can go to my xml files.

Comment: TicToc, is the mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: I had a problema with my system,  it works now. thanks .

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.xml$ /different_Page.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.xml$
RewriteRule (.*) 404.php [R=301]
```